# Python Dictionary multi values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of colors with multiple values:

```
dictcolors = {'Red': '1,2,3,4,5',
              'Green': '3,4,5',
              'Purple': '6',
              'Orange': '7', 
              'Blue': '1,2,3',
              'Teal': '3,4,5,6'}
```

How can you iterate through all values and return the value and key(s) that the value is a part of?

```
Result:
Value - Key(s)

1 - 'Red', 'Blue'
2 - 'Red', 'Blue'
3 - 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Teal'
4 - 'Red', 'Green', 'Teal'
5 - 'Red', 'Green', 'Teal'
6 - 'Purple', 'Teal'
7 - 'Orange'
```

Comment: Where is your code so far, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong data type. Using dictionaries to look up keys from values is like buying a plane so you can taxi it to work every day. It's slow, inefficient, unwieldy, and you look ridiculous on surface streets.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (available from py 2.6+) for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
foundColors = defaultdict(set)
for key,value in dictcolors.iteritems():
    # Assuming the numbers are in a comma separated string
    for color in value.split(','):
        foundColors[color].add( key )
```

`foundColors` gives:

```
>>defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'1': set(['Blue', 'Red']), '3': set(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red', 'Teal']), '2': set(['Blue', 'Red']), '5': set(['Green', 'Red', 'Teal']), '4': set(['Green', 'Red', 'Teal']), '7': set(['Orange']), '6': set(['Purple', 'Teal'])})
```

Another advantage of using a `defaultdict` is that it wont break when accessing numbers that don't exist in your `dictcolors`. This is because when you accessing such keys, it will initialize the key's value by an empty 'default' type (which is a `set` in this case).

So you can do something like this without a problem:

```
for number in range(10):
    print number,list(foundColors[number])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
integer count = 0;
for key in dictcolors.keys():{
    print '{0}'.format( str(count) ) + ' - '
    if (dictcolors[key].find(str(count)))
        print key
```

Comment: Are you sure this is python?

Comment: sorry, I'm just a beginner in stackoverflow and I haven't the Python GUI.That's why I put the example as an idea.

Comment: That's alright. But for future reference you might want to run your code to check if it's correct. With python its really easy to do. :)